# Drupalchat causing unlimited number of guest users?

Tags: session, drupal-7, chat

After launching my site, I noticed that the guest users jump from 0 to 45 in seconds. It seems to increase without ever stopping. It worked fine locally, but it seems that the "Sessions" aren't sticking and it's thinking each user is a new user.

I'm using Centos, with Drupal 7 and the DrupalChat module. I did add some custom code, but nothing that should cause this. And like I said, it works locally.

I suppose there is a chance that even though the site is hidden from prying eyes, that it could still be something creating 45 viewers. But I dont know what. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

It's probably only getting to 45 users, because it is picking up SOMETHING as a new user, and then losing track of it. 45 seconds later it expires and that user is shown as offline.

**UPDATE**

Every time cron runs, it seems to think a new user is accessing the site. I.e. Every time I open cron.php, it shows the user as active. Why would it be doing that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by setting a session variable when cron runs and then where the module asks on which pages to display it, I return false if the session variable is set.

It's definitely a hack, but the real solution is to propose quite a few changes to the module.